# 'self = this' vs apply or bind? (Backbone)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Often in my Backbone code I come across situations where I would be passing a closure to some function and lose context of 'this'.

My solution for some time had been to do what I had seen some others do:

```
var self = this;

this.deferred.done(function () {
    self.render();
});
```

Or actually I switched to `_this = this`, but that's beside the point. It works, but it feels ugly and I sometimes have to do it quite often. So I'm trying to figure out a better way to do this. I learned I could do this:

```
this.deferred.done(function () {
    this.render();
}.apply(this));
```

And I think I could also use Underscore to do this:

```
this.deferred.done(_.bind(function () {
    self.render();
}, this));
```

The `apply` method seems the most succinct but I feel like it has a side effect (I just don't know what it is yet).

Edit:

Take a look at this JSbin where I use apply similar to as I mentioned:
http://jsbin.com/qobumu/edit?js,console

It works, yet it throws an error at the same time. If I change the `apply` to `bind`, it works and doesn't throw an error.

Comment: `.apply()` is almost certainly not what you want; I think you're thinking of `Function.prototype.bind()`.

Comment: `this.deferred.done(this.render.bind(this))` works without typing the word
 "function" or duping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [*Function*.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is a native method, no need for underscore unless you're coding for antique browsers. Exactly what @dandavis said: `this.deferred.done(this.render.bind(this))` (but note that `bind` can also bind function arguments, not just `this`)
- if you're actually coding for cutting-edge browsers or node.js 4, you can use arrow functions which bind `this` lexically to whatever it is in the scope where the function is defined, so you could write:
  `this.deferred.done(() => { this.render() });`

Comment: This is very interesting. A nice look at the future but I need better browser support than arrow functions have. Bind seems to work just like apply, but I now notice that apply throws an error (I'll add more to my original question.)

Comment: Yes, because `apply` executes the function immediately, as Alex explains in his answer. Not useful for callbacks.

Answer (score 4):

Those do different things.

```
// returns a function with `this` set to what you want.
_.bind(fn, this);
// or
fn.bind(this);

// EXECUTES the function with `this` set to what you want.
fn.apply(this);
```

So in your case it's not a callback at all. When you use `apply` you are *executing* the function when you think you are assigning the callback.

This is why you use bind.